# Hidden submit button inside 'form-horizontal' form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Say I have the next form:

```
<form action="/orders/add" class="form-horizontal" id="OrderAddForm" method="post">
   <div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"></div>         

   <div class="control-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn" id="new-order-line">New order line</button>
   </div>

   <div class="control-group">
      <input class="btn my-hidden" type="submit" value="Save Orderr">       
   </div>
</form>
```

And my css:

```
.my-hidden {
   display: none;
}
```

And my js:

```
$(function() {
   $('#new-order-line').click(function() {
     $('.my-hidden').show('slow');
   });
});
```

So I want to display the 'Save Order' button whenever I click the 'New order line' button, but it seems that Twitter Bootstrap override my 'my-hidden' class because is inside of a 'form' element and my 'Save Order' button is always shown.
I've read that some people have [the same problem](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4079)

Some workaround to hide my button?

Comment: You have a typo in your JS.  `$('.my-hidden').show('slow');` vs `$('.my-hidden').show('show');`

Comment: @cimmanon `show('show')` ? I think `show('slow')` is ok.

Comment: Yup, @enrmarc is correct about `show('slow')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't view this as a problem per se. It may not be (easily) done with Twitter Bootstrap CSS rules but if the problem is that Twitter Bootstrap overrides what you want to do, you can always create your own rules with higher [specificity](https://www.google.se/search?q=css+specificity&aq=0&oq=css+specif&aqs=chrome.0.0j57j0l2j62l2.2255&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

One easy way would be to add to the attributes `style="display: none;"` since inline styles automatically enjoy top specificity.

A way of giving your class higher specificity is elaborating the selector a bit. For example, this has a higher specificity than your example but I don't know if it's enough:

```
.form-horizontal .control-group .my-hidden { display: none; }
```

(I hope I understood your problem correctly... berate me if not ;)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, you've understood the problem. I've reading about this problem in the issues list of Twitter Bootstrap and I think that is still not working. I will try disable the button instead of show it.

Comment: It's great that you researched it thoroughly enough that you found that thread. I read it now, and yes that sounds like the problem you're having. But it was supposed to have been corrected since 2.1.0 and it is now on version 2.2.2, so if you're using the latest version you shouldn't have that problem. Also, TB is nothing but a set of CSS rules, you can, like I said, always create new rules with higher specificity, to override whatever TB does. So it is always possible to hide something if you just give your rule high enough specificity.